# MWE with Hyperref's next-anchor option

Tags: hyperref

I would like to use the option `next-anchor` with the hyperref package. The documentation says I can use it like this:

```
\hypersetup{next-anchor=toc}
\tableofcontents
\bookmark[dest=\HyperDestNameFilter{toc},level=section]{\contentsname}
```

But I get the error that \bookmark wasn't defined. What I want to understand is why it would tell me to use \bookmark. This is a command from another package, and it does not even tell so. I am interested in using the option `next-anchor` but not load the package `bookmark`. How does a minimal working example look that uses hyperref commands only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something similar can't be shown with `hyperref` as its `\pdfbookmark` command creates both an anchor and a bookmark; it can't reference an anchor created in some other way. You could create a bookmark similar to the one you get with `\bookmark` only with internal commands. Regardless of the `next-anchor` option I recommend to always load the bookmark package, it offers more options and bookmarks are created faster (already in the first compilation). At some time in the future the package will be merged into hyperref anyway.

If you want an example without bookmark you could create a link:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\hypersetup{next-anchor=toc}
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\hyperlink{toc}{link to the toc}

\section{abc}
\end{document}
```

While this work it is (unlike the example with a bookmark to the toc) not something that is often requested and so it is more of theoretical interest. I added a clarification to the docu that `\bookmark` is from the bookmark package.